# Relation between one dimensional Schrodinger's operator and Riemann hypothesis

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, operator-theory, riemann-hypothesis

At the end of lecture ( from conference "Perspectives on Riemann hypothesis" '18 ) S.J. Patterson mentioned about work done by 'Christa Mirgel' ( University of Gottingen) on one dimensional Schrodinger's operator relating Riemann zeros .

I searched on Google for this work but in vain . ( Found similar profile on LinkedIn but seems he left academia )

> So , if anyone has detailed reference about it Please share .
>
> Also , In  general is there any serious progress in this direction 'recently'?

Comment: https://aimath.org/wp-content/uploads/bristol-2018-slides/Patterson-talk.pdf refers to "Christa Mirgel – Diplomarbeit, Göttingen, 1985"

Comment: @Keith McClary , I know that , but can't seem to find the original paper .